# Listen changes on page using JxBrowser

Tags: javascript, java, jxbrowser

In Java project I use `JxBrowser`.

I have page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Start: <input type="text" id="startTimeField"> ms
<hr>
<button id="buttonToClick" onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById('startTimeField').value = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I load page correct with JxBrowser.

When button "Start" is clicked, then value of the text input is setted.

I want add listener using JxBrowser object in Java to listen `startTimeField` text input changes.

Ex:
`startTimeField` is setted by 0, after click `Start` button the field change value (by actual ms time) and I want detect this changes in Java code and get the value of change.

Comment: You may want to fix this: `("startTimeField)` you forgot the double quote, so it must be `("startTimeField")`

Comment: Thanks I correct it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question basically asks how to listen to events in the DOM in Java, I think this is what you are looking for:

[JxBrowser - DOM Events](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013095-dom-events)

You will have to do something similar to this (in your Java code):

```
DOMElement element = browser.getDocument().findElement(By.id("startTimeField"));
element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnChange, new DOMEventListener() {
    public void handleEvent(DOMEvent event) {
        // your code for reacting to the change here
    }
}, false);
```

I did not test this code but adapted it from the documentation, so it might not compile and work right away, but this should lead you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="startTimeField" onchange="yourfunction">
```

Look at the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)