# Listen to changes of field by Swt Eclipse browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, eclipse, swt

In Java project I used `SWT Eclipse` as a Browser.

I run this browser and loaded page fine.

Page which is loaded looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Start: <input type="text" id="startTimeField" onchange="myFunction()" placeholder="Type text and press Enter"> ms

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById('startTimeField').value = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to listen element from page in Java code.

Example what I want achieve:
In Java press JButton, which should find button with id `startTimeField` from page and add listener to them. Listener should listen to change value of this field. How to do this ?

Comment: Looks like you're planning to mix SWT and Swing/AWT. Don't go down that road if you can avoid it. However, you should probably have a look at [this](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/) for the Java<->Javascript interaction you're looking for.

Comment: I want add listener in Java code to listen changes of text input in page by SWT. Do the same thing  as using JxBrowser in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391142/listen-changes-on-page-using-jxbrowser/42391828#42391828)

Comment: Not sure if that's possible at all without modifying the HTML.

Comment: So what You suggest to do ?

Comment: Add the listener in the html and call a Java browser function from within the listener.

Comment: @Baz Can You prepare simple solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple example with two HTML buttons. When clicked they'll call an SWT `BrowserFunction` and pass in the id of the button:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setText("<button id='button1' onclick='buttonClicked(this.id)'>Click me</button><button id='button2' onclick='buttonClicked(this.id)'>Click me</button>");

    new BrowserFunction(browser, "buttonClicked")
    {
        @Override
        public Object function(Object[] objects)
        {
            System.out.println("BUTTON CLICK; ID: " + objects[0]);
            return null;
        }
    };

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```